# MoreLikeThis feature in Lucene .NET 3.0.3 got read past EOF

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, morelikethis

I wrote this simple code to find similar docs with a doc id.

```
using (IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.Open(FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(LuceneDir)), true))
 {
   MoreLikeThis mlt = new MoreLikeThis(indexReader);
   mlt.SetFieldNames(new String[] { "Id", "Title", "Details" });
   Query query = mlt.Like(docId); // Pass the doc id 
 }
```

But in last line I got this `System.IO.IOException: read past EOF`.

Could anyone help me out?.

Comment: could you show where docID comes from?

Comment: This code is inside a method and docId comes from parameter of that method :D

Comment: could you show a value for this docId when you got this exception?

Comment: `docId` is 1123 when I got error

Comment: do you have that many docs in the index?

Comment: Off course I have, nearly 3000 docs are indexed.